# Bind angular directive template to a event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a angular directive with a template like this

```
<Button id="testBtn">Test me<button>
```

I then have a directive controller where i have my API functions for the directive. 
I now need to pass a event to the calling module that the button was clicked.So that i can define what to do on the button click in my base application.

Something like this must go in the baseApp controller.

```
$scope.myDirective = {
    btnClick:function(){
     //define the function here
    }
}
```

My html template would look something like this

```
<my-simpledirective='myDirective'></my-simpledirective>
```

I have got to the part where i can declare my configurations in the $scope.myDirective = {} , but how can i do event definition there ?

FYI: This is the way kendoUI is doing it , want to do it in the same way.

*Something like this would also be acceptable*

```
<my-simpledirective='myDirective' btn-clicked="myCustomClick"></my-simpledirective>
```

then in the baseApp controller

```
$scope.myCustomClick = function(){
 //called when click event received
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up scope two-way binding to configuration object from controller:

```
app.directive('mySimpledirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            config: '='
        },
        template: '<Button id="testBtn">{{config.label}}</button>',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on('click', function(e) {
                scope.config.btnClick(e);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and pass it in template as follows:

```
<my-simpledirective config='myDirective'></my-simpledirective>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/ue8EX9OR17iQxIi1ekco?p=preview

Comment: Thanks , have been using 2 way binding for so long but did not think of this ...lol